# Event Calendar in MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, calendar

I want to fulfill this functionality:
 Calendar by month pops up with event names written on the calendar
 Access a daily event summary by clicking a day in the calendar

Please tell me from where shall I start

Thanks
Ritz

Answer (score 0):

Use [Jquery UI Datepicker](http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/) widget. You can do almost everything calendar related with this.

Answer (score 0):

You can try [DayPilot Pro for MVC](http://mvc.daypilot.org/) (my product).

Here is a tutorial for using the monthly view with a database:

- http://mvc.daypilot.org/monthly-calendar-and-sql-server-tutorial/